# error: use of class template 'HashTable' requires template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, hashtable

I'm writing a program to create a hash table, while giving the option to insert and delete a value from the table. I'm soon going to add an option to create a new table for all data types, an need to use a template for the hash table class. But this error message "error: use of class template 'HashTable' requires template arguments" keeps appearing, anyone have any ideas why? Thank you.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// ------------ Hash table ------------

template <class T>
class HashTable{

    private:
        vector<T> arrayofbuckets[100];

    public:
         void insertelement(string input);
         void deleteelement(string remove);

}; // end of class

// ------------ MAIN ------------ 

int main()
{

HashTable hash;

// Creating the menu

char selection;
string Element;
string ElementDelete;

do{
cout << "--------------- Menu ---------------";
cout << "\n Press i to insert an element into the hash table";
cout << "\n Press d to delete an element from the hash table";

// Read the input

cin >> selection;

switch(selection)
{

// Inserting an element

case 'I':
case 'i':
{
    cout << " Which element would you like to insert?: ";
    cin >> Element;

    hash.insertelement(Element);

    }
break;

// Delete an element

case 'D':
case 'd':
{
    cout << " Which element would you like to delete?: ";
    cin >> ElementDelete;

    hash.deleteelement(ElementDelete);

    }
break;


// Exit the program

case 'e': {cout << "Goodbye! :D";}
break;

// Display message if input is not I, D, L, S, P or E

default : cout << "\n Invalid selection";
}

cout<<"\n";

} while(selection != 'e');

return 0;

} // End of main

// ------------ Functions for chained hash tables ------------

// Inserting an element

template <class T>
void HashTable<T>::insertelement(string input){

    T hashValue = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++){

        hashValue = hashValue + int(input[i]);

    }

    hashValue = hashValue % 100; // HASH FUNCTION

    arrayofbuckets[hashValue].push_back(input);

    cout << " The element " << input << " has been put into value " << hashValue << endl;

} // End of insert function

// Deleting an element

 template <class T>
 void HashTable<T>::deleteelement(string remove){

    T hashValue = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < remove.length(); i++){

        hashValue = hashValue + int(remove[i]);
    }

    hashValue = hashValue % 100; // HASH FUNCTION

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<arrayofbuckets[hashValue].size();){

        if (arrayofbuckets[hashValue].at(i)==remove){
            arrayofbuckets[hashValue].erase(arrayofbuckets[hashValue].begin()+i);

    cout << " The element " << remove << " has been deleted from bucket " << hashValue << endl;

 } else {
            i++;
 }
}
} // End of delete function
```

Comment: Post the full error message in your post.

Comment: It is a template class; of course it needs a template argument!

Comment: You defined your HashTable class a template, but you didn't create it as such. instead of `HashTable hash;` create it as `HashTable<Type_of_member> hash;`

Answer (score 2):

What type are you wanting to hash? Decide on that. Let's say it's `Y`. Then you need to replace

`HashTable hash;`

with

`HashTable<Y> hash;`

If you want `Y` to be a `std::string` then you have some work to do. `hashValue % 100` will be meaningless for a string type. Consider using `std::hash` instead? Then bin the whole thing and use `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the template parameter `T`:

```
HashTable<string> hash;
      // ^^^^^^^^
```